# Is there a way to automatically import 'cssuseragent' (or any non-exported) package in webpack?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

Current [cssuseragent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cssuseragent) package (2.1.31) doesn't export anything. There is only one variable named cssua. I want import/require it into my project with webpack.

I have tried to adding export keyword before cssua variable and it worked. But this is not a good solution. If anybody else upgrade the package in future, she/he won't know that s/he must do this.

In CLI:

```
npm i cssuseragent
```

Then I export cssua variable:

```
//'export' was not exist, I added it
export var cssua = (
//some code here
)(/*some arguments here*/)
```

Then I can import:

```
import { cssua } from 'cssuseragent';
```

Is there any way to say "If you resolve to this file in import/require, get it as 'custom-name' with its all content" to webpack with a loader or plugin? Because changing source code of a 3rd party module is not a good way. Also it may not be as easy as this every time, the module can be huge. And I want a generic way to do this, maybe like adding just the path of module.

Comment: You can create a pull request on Github for this.

Comment: @madflow Of course I can create a pull request for this but I can't create pull requests for each package that not using export. We can't wait until the request is confirmed, my request may not be confirmed or library may be complex and unable to edit. I mean my problem is not related only with cssua, it is related with every non-exported package.

Comment: Yeah :/  Can't you just use `import 'cssuseragent';` and use the globaly exported variable (if exists :/ ).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a webpack plugin that does that, but you can

```
// customExport.js
import { cssua } from 'cssuseragent';
export default { cssua };
```

in another file

```
// other_file,js
import customExport from "customExport.js";
```